# Android - Talk to an active Fragment from Main Activity

Tags: android

I have a Main Activity with a bunch of Fragments connected to it.

One of the fragments has to be able to recieve data from MainActivity *after* it has been loaded in the FragmentTransaction and committed.

What is the best way to call a method in that specific fragment?

Do I have to implement a Interface and include it in the MainActivty just for this one fragment? Is there a better way? Can someone point me in the correct direction?

What I have tried now : (Failing at settings ContactsInterface in the MainActivity)

**ContactsInterface**

```
public interface ContactsInterface {

   void notifyDenied();
   void notifyGranted();
```

}

**Fragment**

```
Class.... implements ContactsInterface...

@Override
public void notifyDenied() {
    Log.d("DENIED", "DENIED CALLBACK");
}
@Override
public void notifyGranted() {
    Log.d("GRANTED", "GRANTED CALLBACK");
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
try {
     contactsInterface = (ContactsInterface) this.getApplicationContext();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
     throw new ClassCastException(this.toString()
                + " Needs to implement the methods");
}
```

Last example throws an ClassCastException.

Comment: `contactsInterface = (ContactsInterface) fragment;` i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the fragment itself not the Application Context.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

ContactsInterface contactsInterface = (ContactsInterface) fragment;

//contactsInterface.notifyGranted();
//contactsInterface.notifyDenied();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the active fragments in the `FragmentManager` and filter for the ones that have the required interface:

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments
    .map { it as? ContactsInterface }
    .filterNotNull()
    .forEach {
        it.notifyDenied()
    }
```

or if you need to use `Java`:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

for(fragment : fragments) {
    if(fragment instanceof ContactsInterface) {
        ((ContactsInterface)fragment).notifyDenied();
    }
}
```

You may want to also fail (hard or soft) if no fragments are found.

The advantage of doing this is that you don't care how the fragment was started (manually or by layout) and also don't have to care about reconnecting when the activity restarts for example.

Answer (score 0):

This [library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) may be useful to you.

You should do something like this in your fragment:

```
@Override
 public void onCreateView() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

MessageEvent is just an example, you can use whatever structure you want.

in the Activity you post messages like this:

EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());

Check the documentation of the library to have a better idea and use a better approach to your case.

you can use onCreate() and onDestroy() instead. That depends on your logic and you you are updating the view of the fragment when you receive new messages from the Activity.

Happy coding :).